# Book class list of figures with subfigures listed in paragraph format

Tags: table-of-contents, subcaption, titletoc

For a report I am writing, there is a page limit and I have to include lists of figures/schemes/tables. I would like for the figure caption to be standard (i.e. `1.1  Testing ....... 1`) and for subfigures to appear in paragraph format so it occupies as few lines as possible. Ideally I would like for the main figure to appear like `1.1`, `1.2`:

[image]

but for subfloats (subfigures in this case) to appear similar to the [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) documentation TOC (`2.1 Format, 2.` etc):

[image]

Is this possible? It looks challenging and I haven't seen a question on this before for subfigures on TeX.SE although I would welcome if this was a duplicate. My effort so far involves trying to use `titletoc` and adding another definition in (this is adapted from `titletoc.sty`):

```
\makeatletter
\let\ttl@savel@subfigure\l@subfigure
\def\l@subfigure{\ttl@lselect{subfigure}}
\makeatother
```

which is not working at all and probably expected:

[image]

Is there a way for this to be done please? I wouldn't mind a dotted line to the number on the right as they all share the same page number being subfigures but this is probably more of an optimistic dream.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\makeatletter
\let\ttl@savel@subfigure\l@subfigure
\def\l@subfigure{\ttl@lselect{subfigure}}
\makeatother

\titlecontents*{subfigure}[1.5em]
    {\small}
    {\thecontentslabel. }
    {}
    {, \thecontentspage}
    [.---][.]

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{T}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\newpage
\section{T}
\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfig1}\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfig2}\end{subfigure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\newpage
\subsection{TT}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfig1}\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfig2}\end{subfigure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfig1}\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfig2}\end{subfigure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Turns out that if you define `\contentsuse{subfigure}{lof}` and apply the `lof` settings after loading `caption`/`subcaption` then it can be made to work.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsuse{subfigure}{lof}

\makeatletter
\let\ttl@savel@subfigure\l@subfigure
\def\l@subfigure{\ttl@lselect{subfigure}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}

\titlecontents*{subfigure}[3.9em]
    {\small}
    {\thecontentslabel. }
    {}
    {, \thecontentspage}
    [. --- ][.]


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{T}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\newpage
\section{T}
\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfigOne}\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfigTwo}\end{subfigure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\newpage
\subsection{TT}
\begin{figure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfigOne}\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfigTwo}\end{subfigure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfigOne}\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}\caption{subfigTwo}\end{subfigure}\caption{Testing}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```